# concatenating values from rows in based on criteria

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, paste

I have a dataframe `df` (see code below) which contains close to 100,000 rows showing the list of my program's contacts. The list has a column showing the program `program` and organization `O_ID` with which the contact is associated and a column for the role the contact has in the program. Whenever a contact is in more than one program or has more than one role in the program another line is created for that contact with the program and contact role field values changing.

```
First   Last    C_ID    OrgName O_ID Program    Role
John    Smith   10045   Acme    901 Buildings   Primary
John    Smith   10045   Acme    901 Buildings   Communications
John    Smith   10045   Acme    901 Homes       Primary
Teddy   Bush    10046   Acme    901 Buildings   Primary
Teddy   Bush    10046   Acme    901 Buildings   Signatory
Jess    Clinton 10050   Consult 904 Homes       Signatory
Jess    Clinton 10050   Consult 904 Homes       Primary
Jess    Clinton 10050   Consult 904 Homes       Communications
```

For presentation purposes I am trying to minimize the number of lines. Specifically, if a contact is in the same organization and the same program, I only want the contact to appear on one line (versus several at the moment) and to combine the contact roles into one string.

I tried this code and it partially works: `ddply(df,.(df$C_ID, df$Program, df$O_ID), paste, sep=",")`

Here are the results:

```
df$C_ID df$Program df$O_ID                        V1                                 V2
1       10045      Buildings         901         c("John", "John")                c("Smith", "Smith")
2       10045          Homes         901                      John                              Smith
3       10046      Buildings         901       c("Teddy", "Teddy")                  c("Bush", "Bush")
4       10050          Homes         904 c("Jess", "Jess", "Jess") c("Clinton", "Clinton", "Clinton")
                      V3                                 V4               V5                           V6
1        c(10045, 10045)                  c("Acme", "Acme")      c(901, 901)  c("Buildings", "Buildings")
2                  10045                               Acme              901                        Homes
3        c(10046, 10046)                  c("Acme", "Acme")      c(901, 901)  c("Buildings", "Buildings")
4 c(10050, 10050, 10050) c("Consult", "Consult", "Consult") c(904, 904, 904) c("Homes", "Homes", "Homes")
                                           V7
1              c("Primary", "Communications")
2                                     Primary
3                   c("Primary", "Signatory")
4 c("Signatory", "Primary", "Communications")
```

The problem is

1)  The columns were rearranged (note there are many more columns in my actual dataset) and column names disappeared

2)  The only column with changed values should be in the `Role` column. However, the results are combining the values for most columns even when the merged values are the same. For example, in the results column `V1` (the first name column), returns `c("John", "John")`. It should just read "John". The only column that should have different values would be column `V7` `c("Primary", "Communications")`

```
df<-structure(list(First = c("John", "John", "John", "Teddy", "Teddy", 
"Jess", "Jess", "Jess"), Last = c("Smith", "Smith", "Smith", 
"Bush", "Bush", "Clinton", "Clinton", "Clinton"), C_ID = c(10045L, 
10045L, 10045L, 10046L, 10046L, 10050L, 10050L, 10050L), OrgName = c("Acme", 
"Acme", "Acme", "Acme", "Acme", "Consult", "Consult", "Consult"
), O_ID = c(901L, 901L, 901L, 901L, 901L, 904L, 904L, 904L), 
    Program = c("Buildings", "Buildings", "Homes", "Buildings", 
    "Buildings", "Homes", "Homes", "Homes"), Role = c("Primary", 
    "Communications", "Primary", "Primary", "Signatory", "Signatory", 
    "Primary", "Communications")), .Names = c("First", "Last", 
"C_ID", "OrgName", "O_ID", "Program", "Role"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need in `paste` is `collapse = ", "`, not `sep`. Using a `collapse` creates a single string from all the inputs. I'm doing this by grouping on all the identifying columns—names, orgs, programs, etc—and then collapsing the roles in `summarise`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(First, Last, C_ID, OrgName, O_ID, Program) %>%
  summarise(roles_mult = paste(Role, collapse = ", "))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#> # Groups:   First, Last, C_ID, OrgName, O_ID [?]
#>   First Last     C_ID OrgName  O_ID Program   roles_mult                  
#>   <chr> <chr>   <int> <chr>   <int> <chr>     <chr>                       
#> 1 Jess  Clinton 10050 Consult   904 Homes     Signatory, Primary, Communi…
#> 2 John  Smith   10045 Acme      901 Buildings Primary, Communications     
#> 3 John  Smith   10045 Acme      901 Homes     Primary                     
#> 4 Teddy Bush    10046 Acme      901 Buildings Primary, Signatory
```

Comment: To make it even more concise, I think you can replace the existing `group_by` with `group_by_at(vars(-Role))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `dplyr` as well.

```
> df %>% distinct(First, Last, .keep_all=T)
  First    Last  C_ID OrgName O_ID   Program      Role
1  John   Smith 10045    Acme  901 Buildings   Primary
2 Teddy    Bush 10046    Acme  901 Buildings   Primary
3  Jess Clinton 10050 Consult  904     Homes Signatory
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the information I was looking for. John Smith, for example, has multiple roles. The Role column should show "Primary, Communications" for the Building Program. He should also have an additional line for his participation in the Homes program.

Comment: I see your point now. It's still doable with another modification for your need.